# Converting a hex String to an int in Java

Tags: java, regex, hex

I am trying to convert a a hex String into an int, but no matter what I try I keep getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0xE0030000".
I use the following pattern in my code:

```
    String ecuPattern ="(\\s*)(ECU_ADDRESS )(0xE0\\d*\\w*\\d*)";

    if(mt.find()){
        String stringNumber = mt.group(3);
        long number = Long.parseLong(stringNumber, 16);
```

Can you please tell me what I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you use `Long.parseLong(value, 16)` you do not need to use `0x` at the beginning of hex representation of number.

Comment: @Ivan is correct, to solve the issue you can just change your regex to `"(\\s*)(ECU_ADDRESS )0x(E0\\d*\\w*\\d*)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems incomplete, but based on your exception message, the input for Long.parseLong should be "E0030000" and NOT "0xE0030000".

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String hex="E0030000";  
    Long decimal=Long.parseLong(hex,16);  
    System.out.println(decimal);
}
```

output: 3758292992

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `decode()` and leave the "0x" in if you prefer.

```
String hex="0xE0030000";  
long decimal=Long.decode(hex);
```

From the Javadoc:

> Decodes a String into a Long. Accepts decimal,
>        hexadecimal, and octal numbers given by the following
>        grammar:
>
> ```
>  DecodableString:
>     Signopt DecimalNumeral 
>     Signopt 0x HexDigits 
>     Signopt 0X HexDigits 
>     Signopt # HexDigits 
>     Signopt 0 OctalDigits
> ```